# Chrome DevTools are not appearing ONLY on Google Forms page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to inspect elements of a Form for an Apps Script.  DevTools are available on every other page I load EXCEPT Google Forms.

I have searched in the devtools settings to find a blacklisted page, but nothing is there, also there is nothing in the registry for developer tools in the chrome folder.

I have found no solutions searching the internet for this, only general solutions when devtools is completely turned off.

I will add that I recently tried to use the "Dynamic Fields" add on for forms to accomplish the task of dynamic drop downs on my form before I decided to do it myself with Apps Script.  This add-on probably does not want people peeking behind the curtain so they may have disabled the ability to see their code?  Is this plausible?

Comment: Try invoking Devtools from the browser menu -> more tools -> developer tools.

Comment: I have tried that, it does nothing.

Comment: Is there a way that an Add-On can change this for a specific website like google forms?  I cleared the cache and cookies and nothing changed.   One other note is that it is only on one of my PC's that I have this problem, on the other, the "Inspect" option on right-click is not grayed out.  The PC that it IS grayed out on is the one that I installed a specific forms related add-on to chrome.  I since removed it but I wonder if there are some remnants of it lying around.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This not only happens in google forms but also google classroom. Come to think of it, it looks like google is doing something with disabling Developer Tools on some of their sites. Others have complained that it is also disabled on their university/educational institution’s site. The main reason for this is to probably prevent “hacking” on these sites. Quick searches on google return almost no results on this phenomenon. It is definitely on a per-website basis, and probably not because of a local policy.

Answer (score 0):

Update: If you are using Google Chrome as your browser, the devtools may not work on certain google products.

NOTE: This is for when individual webpages block inspect element, be sure it is enabled in the first place!

The Solution:
Use a different browser, as it seems to only happen on Chrome. (I used Firefox, but other browsers should be fine too.)